# calculating input fields by class name

Tags: javascript, calculator

Here is my form:

```
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="input1" SIZE=10>
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="input2" SIZE=10>
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="+" name="add"
onclick="CalculateIMSUB(this.form)">
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="Answer" SIZE=12>
```

Here is my function:

```
function CalculateIMSUB(form) {
var Atext = form.input1.value;
var Btext = form.input2.value;
var val = form.val.value;
var A = eval(Atext);
var B = eval(Btext);    
var answer = A - B;
form.Answer.value = answer;
}
```

Here is my question:
I want my function to operate through classname. So, if my form were to look like this instead:

```
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT classNAME="input1" name="baboon" SIZE=10>
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT classNAME="input2" name="gorilla" SIZE=10>
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="+" name="add"
onclick="CalculateIMSUB(this.form)">
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="Answer" SIZE=12>
```

The calculater function would still work.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following to retrieve the element:

```
function CalculateIMSUB(form) {
var Atext = form.getElementById('input1').value;
var Btext = form.getElementById('input2').value;
var val = form.val.value;
var A = eval(Atext);
var B = eval(Btext);    
var answer = A - B;
form.Answer.value = answer;
}
```

for the following HTML:

```
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT id="input1" name="baboon" SIZE=10>
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT id="input2" name="gorilla" SIZE=10>
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="+" name="add"
onclick="CalculateIMSUB(this.form)">
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="Answer" SIZE=12>
```

Comment: no worries Clint, everybody here is a nice person. that's why we helping each other. ;)

Answer (score 0):

instead of class use id instead and you can reference them by using document.getElementById('ID').value there is a document.getElementByClass i think but it's  not fully supported by all browsers

Answer (score 0):

```
function getElementsByClassName(oElm, strTagName, strClassName){
    var arrElements = (strTagName == "*" && oElm.all)? oElm.all :
        oElm.getElementsByTagName(strTagName);
    var arrReturnElements = new Array();
    strClassName = strClassName.replace(/\-/g, "\\-");
    var oRegExp = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + strClassName + "(\\s|$)");
    var oElement;
    for(var i=0; i < arrElements.length; i++){
        oElement = arrElements[i];
        if(oRegExp.test(oElement.className)){
            arrReturnElements.push(oElement);
        }
    }
    return (arrReturnElements)
}
```